# How to solve java error on Geoserver GSR extension

Tags: java, spring, geoserver

I have set up a Geoserver instance. Now I need the GSR extension to have an ArcGIS compatible REST API.
I installed the extension as described but on Geoserver startup I get a couple of errors and when I access the webpage a HTTP error 503.
I already tried different versions of Geoserver and JDK, all with the same result.
Here is the Java error:

> 11:52:17.791 [main] ERROR
> org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization
> failed org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
> creating bean with name 'gsrDispatcher' defined in URL
> [jar:file:/home/nico/gs/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/gs-gsr-2.21-SNAPSHOT.jar!/applicationContext.xml]:
> Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is
> javax.xml.stream.FactoryConfigurationError: Provider for
> javax.xml.stream.XMLOutputFactory cannot be found

Thanks for any hint,
best regards
Nico

I did some more research and tested the following versions each with both openjdk version ("1.8.0_312" & "11.0.14.1"):

geoserver-2.18-SNAPSHOT-gsr-plugin.zip
Geoserver version:
2.18.2-6
Running without problems

geoserver-2.19-SNAPSHOT-gsr-plugin.zip
Geoserver version:
2.19.0-5
Problem: Error creating bean with name 'geoServicesExceptionResolver'

geoserver-2.19-SNAPSHOT-gsr-plugin.zip
Geoserver version:
2.19.6
Problem: Error creating bean with name 'gsrDispatcher'

geoserver-2.20-SNAPSHOT-gsr-plugin.zip
Geoserver version:
2.20.0-4
Problem: Error creating bean with name 'gsrDispatcher'

geoserver-2.21-SNAPSHOT-gsr-plugin.zip
Geoserver version:
2.21
Problem: Error creating bean with name 'gsrDispatcher'

So it seems something happened between geoserver version 2.18.6 and 2.19.0 and something more happened between version 2.19.5 and 2.19.6.
It would be helpful if someone could give me the contact of the community GSR extenstion. I can not find anything about it.
To get my geoserver updated it would be great to have this fixed soon.
Many thanks in advance.

Comment: which exact versions of GeoServer and JDK did you try? that extension will work with the **main** 2.21.x build (and probably no other) and it will only work with JDK 8 and 11 for sure. Plus it is a community module it may not work at all.

Comment: I tried it with version 2.20.3, 2.20.4, 2.21 and the appropriate GSR extension versions. All with same results. I also tried both Java versions.
I now got it running using Geoserver version 2.18.1 and openjdk 1.8.0_322 but would like to upgrade as soon as possible...

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you're installing the same plugin version for the same GeoServer version you're having.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you have did something wrong in `applicationContext.xml` file.

Comment: Please read [answer]. As it stands, this is very vague. What's wrong in that file, how can the OP resolve the error ..? Please [edit] the answer for clarity.